# Shouldn't an object and its clone (correctly done) byte representations be same?

Tags: java, stream, arrays, equals

Shouldn't an `Object` and its *clone* (correctly done) byte representations be same?

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
oos.writeObject(p);
byte[] byteArr1 = bos.toByteArray();

bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
oos.writeObject(p.clone());
byte[] byteArr2 = bos.toByteArray();
```

---

`Arrays.equals(byteArr1, byteArr2) == true` ?

Trying to see if there are any alternatives to not implementing equals method when comparing an object and its clone. Yes sure, these are not the best practices but I am just trying to understand the byte stream representation of a `Serializable Object`.

Comment: What is "correctly done" ?

Comment: Nothing special, by correctly, I meant same values on all properties in the clone. @user2864740 makes sense, that makes this another dumb question!

Comment: What is the p object?

Comment: Sorry about that, p here is just a regular java object

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are equal. Serialization depends on class and object fields. As soon as both class and fields are the same serialized data will be the same.

```
public class Test implements Cloneable, Serializable {
    int i = 1;

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test t = new Test();
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        oos.writeObject(t);
        byte[] byteArr1 = bos.toByteArray();

        bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        oos.writeObject(t.clone());
        byte[] byteArr2 = bos.toByteArray();

        System.out.println(Arrays.equals(byteArr1, byteArr2));
    }
}
```

prints `true`

Also take a look at common-lang `EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(obj1, obj2)`  it can test any objects  for equality by analizing their fields

Comment: I see there is an option to customize serialization writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out),  readObject(ObjectInputStream in) but that defeats my purpose. Again, I was just playing around to see if we can implement another equivalent of equals() method without actually implementing it. As @user2864740 mentioned, I tried comparing a serialized object with no collections and it still failed, so it won't work on any object for that matter unless you customize serialization. Let me test by overriding serialization

Comment: OK, I added a test, try it

Comment: But the test checks serilized bytes, true means bytes are same

Comment: @Evgeniy, add an arraylist or a map and see it fails. private List<String> strs = new ArrayList<String>();
 protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
  ...clone.setStrs(new ArrayList<String>(this.strs)); Again as other user mentioned, we don't know how serialization works.

Comment: Cannot use equals builder, it does not enforce clone does not point to a different reference, correct clone creates a different object and does not point to the same reference. ""I am trying to unit test my clone implementation"". I also needed a default value initializer on my object (almost done writing) so I don't miss a new field and make sure none of them are nulls.

Comment: @user469718 but you were talking about correctly implemented clone

Comment: A correct clone makes a copy of an object and does not point to same reference and I am trying to test my clone implementation. EqualsBuilder only checks equality but not if they are different objects (not same object references).

Answer (score 0):

*Not necessarily*: the serialized version of two different objects does *not* need to be byte-equals for the two objects to be `equals`.

There is nothing in the [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) contract that makes any relationship between `equals` and the result of `writeObject`. Furthermore, from the [Serialized Form (writeObject) documentation for Hashtable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/serialized-form.html#java.util.Hashtable):

> .. [and Hashtable serializes] the key (Object) and value (Object) for each key-value mapping represented by the Hashtable The key-value mappings are *emitted in no particular order*.

While, when I say two *different* objects above I mean "created independently", because I think it makes a better case overall, let's consider the contract for [Object.clone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()) to ascertain that it adds no additional restrictions (in fact, `clone` *loses* the `equals` restriction):

> Creates and returns a copy of this object. The precise meaning of "copy" may depend on the class of the object. The *general intent* is that, for any object x, the expression:
>
> ```
> x.clone() != x
> ```
>
> will be true, and that the expression:
>
> ```
> x.clone().getClass() == x.getClass()
> ```
>
> will be true, but these are not absolute requirements. While it is *typically* the case that:
>
> ```
> x.clone().equals(x)
> ```
>
> will be true, this is not an absolute requirement.

As a further counter-example of `clone` implying an object which has the exact same serialized representation, consider an object that implements `clone` *using* serialization (which is perfectly valid and done in some languages): since serialization has no such requirement of byte-equality (e.g. ordering, as in the case of Hastable.writeObject), then the restored order of such serialization/deserialization (and later serialization) is not guaranteed either.

Just because such a rule works on all the types/implementations used in practice (and it very likely will), does *not* imply that types for which `byteEquals(serialize(a), serialize(clone(a))` is not true violate any stated contract or are otherwise implemented incorrectly.

---

Here is some code using a `Hashtable` (I choose this type because it *does* implement Serializable and I did find documentation as per above) which *may* exhibit the issue of "equals" while not "byte-equals when serialized":

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static byte[] serialize(Object v) throws java.lang.Exception {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        oos.writeObject(v);
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }
    
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Hashtable v1 = new Hashtable();
        Hashtable v2 = new Hashtable();
        
        int r = 1000;
        for (int x = 0; x <= r; x++) {
            v1.put(x, 0);
            v2.put(r - x, 0);
        }
        
        byte[] byteArr1 = serialize(v1);
        byte[] byteArr2 = serialize(v2);
        
        System.out.println(v1.equals(v2));
        System.out.println(Arrays.equals(byteArr1, byteArr2));
    }
}
```

And, while on Ideone it always is true/true for me, *according to the [OpenJDK implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/Hashtable.java#Hashtable.writeObject%28java.io.ObjectOutputStream%29)* (and previous documentation excerpt), this need not be the case as the order of entries (in the case of collision and chaining) is not well-defined:

```
933     private void More ...writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream s)
934             throws IOException {
935         Entry<K, V> entryStack = null;
936 
937         synchronized (this) {
938             // Write out the length, threshold, loadfactor
939             s.defaultWriteObject();
940 
941             // Write out length, count of elements
942             s.writeInt(table.length);
943             s.writeInt(count);
944 
945             // Stack copies of the entries in the table
946             for (int index = 0; index < table.length; index++) {
947                 Entry<K,V> entry = table[index];
948 
                    /* order of chained entries is not well defined!! */
949                 while (entry != null) {
950                     entryStack =
951                         new Entry<>(0, entry.key, entry.value, entryStack);
952                     entry = entry.next;
953                 }
954             }
955         }
956 
957         // Write out the key/value objects from the stacked entries
958         while (entryStack != null) {
959             s.writeObject(entryStack.key);
960             s.writeObject(entryStack.value);
961             entryStack = entryStack.next;
962         }
963     }
```

(The OpenJDK implementation's [Hashtable.clone](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/Hashtable.java#Hashtable.clone%28%29) does maintains ordering of entries, but I'm omitting it as it does not support the case outlined in the code above; it is trivial to create a custom type conforming to Clonable/Serializable that violates the initial question proposed while not violating any contractual requirements.)

Comment: Is there any particular value to suggesting that `x.clone() != x`?  It would seem a better requirement would be that given `y=x.clone()`, nothing done to `x` should affect `y`, and nothing done to `y` should affect `x`.  For mutable types, that would imply that `x!=y`, but for immutable types it would not.  Except in those rare cases where immutable object references are used to encapsulate identity (i.e. a relationship with other extant references to the same object) rather than value, I can't see why an immutable object shouldn't simply have `clone()` return `this`.

Comment: @supercat I think that returning `this` for immutable objects is probably fine for most purposes (maybe there is a question already dealing with this?) - and doing so does not violate that loose clone contract (e.g. "depend on the class .. general intent .. not absolute requirements"). The exact semantics should probably be specified in the applicable implementation documentation.